# How do I populate a list of vars?

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

I am trying to organize my code so that it doesn't look so dumb.

```
var date = new Date();
  
var tokyo = new Date().toLocaleDateString("ja-JP");
var londo = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");

document.getElementById('Tokyo').innerHTML = tokyo;
document.getElementById('London').innerHTML = london;
```

This may look ok for 2-3 cities but as more & more cities get added, this code will begin to look really redundant/silly.

So I tried to populate the html element li and put each city inside of each li.

```
var cityList = ['london', 'tokyo'];

function populateCities() {
  var list = document.querySelector(".cities");

  var li;
  for (var e = 0; e & lt; cityList.length; e++) {
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cityList[e]));
    list.appendChild(li);
  }

  var date = new Date();

  var tokyo = new Date().toLocaleDateString("ja-JP");
  var londo = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
}

window.onload = populateCities;
```

And instead of displaying each city's date, each li literally puts the city name (text) in it.

I think I need to put the argument instead of the literal in the var but I just don't know enough javascript to fix the above code.

Just trying to learn javascript.  Any help will be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cityList` should be a data structure that holds both the city name and the city code (used by `toLocaleDateString`), for which an object `{}` is more suitable than an array, like so:

```
var cityList = {
  london: "en-GB",
  tokyo: "ja-JP",
  /* more cities and their codes */
};
```

Using a `for..in` loop like `for(var city in cityList)`, we can access the city name via `city` and the city code via `cityList[city]`, and use them to populate the list like so:

```js
var cityList = {
  berlin: "de-DE",
  cairo: "ar-EG",
  london: "en-GB",
  "new york": "en-US",
  paris: "fr-FR",
  seoul: "ko-KR",
  tokyo: "ja-JP"
};

function populateCities() {
  var list = document.querySelector("#cities");
  var date = new Date();

  for (var city in cityList) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    li.textContent = city + ": " + date.toLocaleDateString(cityList[city]);

    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}

window.onload = populateCities;
```

```html
<ul id="cities"></ul>
```

Comment: thanks.  everyone offered the same solution but your explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programatically define your timestamps, you need to add tz information to your city list:

```js
var cityList = ["ja-JP", "en-US"]
```

Then you will be able to use `array.map` to get an array of time by tz:

```js
var date = new Date()
var timeList = cityList.map(tz => date.toLocaleDateString(tz))
```

And you can use that to populate your li elements:

```js
var cityList = ["ja-JP", "en-US"]
var list = document.querySelector(".cities")
var date = new Date()
cityList.forEach(tz => {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date.toLocaleDateString(tz)));
    list.appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul class="cities"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cityList = ['london', 'tokyo'];
var cityListLocalDatesMapping = {
    'london': 'en-US',
    'tokyo': 'ja-JP'
};
// Nothing complex here , you just missed the mapping. i.e for which country which codes should be used in toLocaleDateString function
function populateCities() {
    var list = document.querySelector(".cities");
    var li;
    for (var e = 0; e < cityList.length; e++) {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().toLocaleDateString(cityListLocalDatesMapping[cityList[e]])));
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cityList = ['london','tokyo'];
```

should be

```
var cityList = ['en-US','ja-JP'];
```

and

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cityList[e]));
```

Should be

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().toLocaleDateString(cityList[e])));
```

It doesn't look too clean, but it should work